# BJT 'Hard Saturation' Equivalent for MOSFET?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, bjt

For a BJT, we usually want to hard saturate it by assuming Beta value is very low. This way we can maximize the current at the collector. However, I am not sure what is the equivalent for a MOSFET transistor.

Is there anything similar to Hard Saturation for a MOSFET transistor? If so, how can it be achieved?

Comment: mosfet is a voltage controlled device unlike bjt which is current controlled.

Comment: @MituRaj Yes I know... and indeed MOSFET is acting like a resistor...   in saturation mode its resistance should be close to 0. I am fear that if there any variation that will make this resistance goes out from saturation mode? Should I do anything at the gate to guarantee the MOSFET to run in saturation mode even in any extreme environment/factor?

Comment: If Vgs>2.5 to 3xVgs(th) you are typically achieving rated RdsOn.  More Vgs helps but very little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not have heard of it because 'saturation' in a MOSFET is the opposite of a bipolar transistor. I think you are actually talking about keeping the MOSFET *out* of saturation and minimizing resistance in the *linear* region. This is achieved by maximizing Gate voltage, which is the FET equivalent of maximizing Base current in a bipolar transistor.

[Here's](http://www.chipfind.ru/datasheet/pdf/stmicroelectronics/stp50n06.pdf) an example of Drain current vs Drain-Source voltage for various Gate voltages on a standard power MOSFET. In the steep 'linear' part of each curve the Drain-Source channel acts like a resistor, so current is proportional to voltage. The flat part is where the channel 'saturates' and cannot pass any more current.

This particular MOSFET is rated for 50A maximum, so a Gate voltage of 10V is sufficient to keep it in linear mode well beyond its rating. At 5V it only stays in linear mode to ~15A, and also has higher resistance (which you can tell from the gentler slope below V<sub>DS</sub> of ~1V). It might still be usable for switching lower current, but this FET really needs more than 5V to ensure that it stays fully turned on at high current.

[image]

Comment: I read your answer again and again...  Yes... I misunderstood what "saturation" means

Comment: Please provide attribution as to where the picture came from unless you drew it yourself.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I took the image from a pdf datasheet that I downloaded from somewhere in 2001. I added the part number thinking this would be sufficient attribution, but obviously it isn't enough for this site. The part is obsolete and I could not find any reference to it on ST's website . Hoping the link I added will be sufficient.

Answer (score 5):

A MOSFET will enter its saturation mode and leave the 'linear region' when an appropriate voltage difference between the gate and source has been achieved. For most N-Channel MOSFETS, this is between 8 and 15 volts. 12v Vgs is what I see most drivers providing MOSFETS these days.

To "guarantee the MOSFET to run in saturation mode even in any extreme environment/factor,"

> You must ensure that Vgs never drops below the 'fully-on' range. Refer to your FET datasheet.

This is analogous to the way BJTs work. If you want a maximum output current, you must provide a minimum input current. With MOSFETS, if you want minimum output resistance and 'saturation,' where the FET effectively functions as a current source, you must provide a minimum voltage between the gate and source.

Here is a graph from the [06N03LA](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91203/91203.pdf):

[image: RdsON]

You want your MOSFET to have the same resistance regardless of the current passing through. According to the graph, if Vgs is 10v, the MOSFET will behave like a current source, generating minimal heat in the transistor itself.

Comment: Sorry this may be a dumb question...   for the BJT part you have mentioned "If you want a maximum output current, you must provide a minimum input current."   Do I misunderstand? Does Output Current referring to Ic?  Doesn't maximum output current comes from maximum input current? i.e. Ib = BIc

Comment: @mannok Your configuration in a BJT circuit must be able to source *at least* some current Ib to the base to get maximum collector current. If your configuration cannot meet this minimum, your output will NOT be saturated.

Comment: Please include a link as to where the picture came from.

Comment: @Michael Karas added the link. Meant to include it but forgot.